# TableSort Plugin Problems asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, tablesorter

Ok... let's start: I've this simple table in an asp page

```
         <table id="provasort" class="tablesorter">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>head1</th>
                    <th>heade2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>body1</td>
                    <td>body2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>body3</td>
                    <td>body4</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
```

I've this link to the css file and to the jquery tablesort plugin on the site.master:

```
       <link href="content/style.css"          rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

       <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
```

This is the css file downloaded from the official site of the plugin:

```
    table.tablesorter {
   font-size: 12px;
   background-color: #4D4D4D;
   width: 1024px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    table.tablesorter th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #6E6E6E;
    }

    table.tablesorter td {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 5px;
    }

   table.tablesorter .even {
  background-color: #3D3D3D;
   }

   table.tablesorter .odd {
 background-color: #6E6E6E;
   }

   table.tablesorter .header {
 background-image: url('../Images/bg.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 border-left: 1px solid #FFF;
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
 border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
 padding-left: 30px;
 padding-top: 8px;
 height: auto;

   }

   table.tablesorter .headerSortUp {
 background-image: url('../Images/asc.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
   }

   table.tablesorter .headerSortDown {
 background-image: url('../Images/desc.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
   }
```

The plugin call:

```
$('#provasort').tablesorter()
```

and now my problems:

1) The plugin doesn't sort my table. I click on the column,but nothing happens. The console don't return any error.

2) The css seems to work except for the background-image on the header.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you got the `$(document).ready(function()` around `$('#provasort').tablesorter()` ?

Comment: Seems to work fine here : http://jsfiddle.net/56Xjb/

Comment: yes i see.. but in my case still doesn't work

Comment: If you create a Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) with your current code does it work?

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<table id="provasort" class="tablesorter">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><a>head1</a></th>
                    <th><a>heade2</a></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>body1</td>
                    <td>body2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>body3</td>
                    <td>body4</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
```